# iPhone app installation fails for enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

An app downloaded/installed with enterprise distribution worked fine for long time until now, it suddenly stops with the following errors:

```
<Warning>: Killing xxx.OurApp for app installation
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-9061050010711031503/-1709014265418617978" requested by itunesstored
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app xxx.OurApp
<Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008011
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008011
<Error>: Jul 10 18:10:47  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.h6dNxf/foo_extracted/Payload/OurApp.app/OurApp: 0xe8008015
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.h6dNxf/foo_extracted/Payload/OurApp.app
<Error>: 0x2ffcf000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
<Error>: 0x2ff99000 handle_install: API failed
```

The weird part is, if we do a rollback of the website containing a link to a .plist and a .ipa to one that worked yesterday, it doesn't work any more. So the exact same .plist and .ipa that worked yesterday, today gives the error above.

The only think we can think of is that we increased the version number of the app from 1.0 to 1.3 in xcode before archiving (and enterprise distributing). But then we reverted back to 1.0 but nothing changed.

Anyone with similar problems?

Comment: Maybe your distribution profile expired, or was invalidated. Check the developer portal to find out.

Comment: Yes, sounds like dist profile.

Answer (score 1):

Seemed to be some error in the new .plist. The problem was that since it went through half of the installation process it placed an half installed app and a broken profile on the phone. If removing both the profile and then the app, we could install the old app with old (correct) .plist